# How to format date from yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm to mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: r, date

I have an Order.Date column in my dataset :

```
Order.Date
2019-08-23 19:29
2019-08-23 10:33
```

I'd like to format it to the format below:

```
Order.Date
08/23/2019
08/23/2019
```

I have tried below code :

```
sod$Order.Date<-substr(sod$Order.Date,1,10)

library(lubridate)
sod$Order.Date<- format(ymd(sod$Order.Date), "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Initially, it worked but is giving me trouble later by saying Failed to parse.

Comment: Try `format(as.POSIXct(sod$Order.Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), "%m/%d/%Y")` or with `format(ymd_hm(sod$Order.Date), "%m/%d/%Y")` or `format(as.Date(sod$Order.Date), "%m/%d/%Y")`

Comment: Thanks! it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier option is to convert to `Date` class and `format`

```
format(as.Date(sod$Order.Date), "%m/%d/%Y")
```